# Convert OLEDB Rowset to Queue object in order to multithread and lock

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have an `Execute SQL Task` that returns a table of data using `Full Result Set` used to drive other child processes in parallel. The problem is needing locks on the `Object` so each is processed only once. How can I access the `Object` variable in a C# Script Task and convert into a Queue datatype in order to lock?

The `Execute SQL Task` stores the results in `User::CoreTables`, then I want to get the value in the first row each time:

```
// The line that fails to do the conversion, not sure how to do this
System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string> tablesQueue = (System.Collections.Generic.Queue<string>)Dts.Variables["User::CoreTables"].Value;

lock (tablesQueue)
{
    //If number of rows in queue is greater than 0 then dequeue row for processing
    //and set DoWork to true. Otherwise set DoWork to false as there is nothing to process
    if (tablesQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::TableToProcess"].Value = tablesQueue.Dequeue();
        Dts.Variables["User::DoWork"].Value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::DoWork"].Value = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're going to have a list of work to be done and the above code approximately dequeues an item and assigns it out to local variables. Could you show an prototype of what you think your Control Flow task will look like? Are you open to other approaches for solving this pattern (assuming I understand it well enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Execute SQL Query** stores full result set as OleDB Recordset. You cannot cast it to a *Queue* of strings, even if OleDB recordset contains only one column. So, you have to process OleDB object inside **Script Task**, filling in your Queue.
The following code sample fragment can process OleDB Object variable

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::CoreTables"].Value);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //process datatable row here
}
```

Comment: This works. I also found doing a `Data Flow Task` and using a `Script Component` as a destination will work as well.